# AwaitingReactions is practically not working on mine. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I dont know why but i followed the guide in discord.js about awaiting reactions but it seems it doesnt work on mine. I dont know why. Whenever i hit the emoji it doesnt collect it. I pretty much goes to every answered question here in stackoverflow but i still cannot fix it.

````
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "error",
  /**
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {Message} message
   * @param {String[]} args
   */
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    message.delete({ timeout:2000 })
    var randstr = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5);
    var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    var comb = randstr + randnum;
    var sayEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Console Error #'+ '`' + comb + '`' + ' sent by ' + message.member.user.tag)
        .setDescription('```' + args.join(" ") + '```')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor("BLACK")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter("Copyright ©️  2022, Mythic Realms, or its associates. All Rights Reserved.")

    message.channel.send({embed: sayEmbed}).then(embedMessage => {
    embedMessage.react('✅');
    })
    
        const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && user.id === message.author.id;
        const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 1, time: 5 * 60 * 1000 });
        
    collector.on('collect', () => {
      message.clearReactions();

      console.log('SUCCESS');
    });
  },
};
````

Please help with this bot :< thank you.

Comment: Did you add ```Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS``` intent to your intents?

Comment: Yes i did add the Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a message collector at `message` whereas the reaction itself is at `embedMessage`.

`embedMessage.createReactionCollector` would be the correct.

Plus, said `embedMessage` is within the scope of the `message.send().then()`

You can either assign the return value of the `message.send()` promise to `embedMessage` on the same level so it is accessible by the collector or set the collector inside the `then()` function from `message.send()`

```js
const embedMessage = await message.send(...);
const collector = embedMessage.createReactionCollector(...);
```

or

```js
message.send(...).then(embedMessage => {
  const collector = embedMessage.createReactionCollector(...);
});
```